# Handle requests for dynamically generated radio buttons in Flask when they don't exist

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm building a Flask application where radio buttons are dynamically generated from my database and then the values entered are stored in a SQLite database table.

It works fine when there are ten radio buttons (which is most of the time) but there are certain circumstances where there are less than 10 relevant entries in the database and therefore less than 10 radio buttons are rendered, and when this is the case I get

```
"400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
```

as the form can't validate as it expected there to be 10 forms numbered 1 to 10. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

```
feedback_list = []
for i in range(1,11):
    feedback = request.form['change_weight_'+str(i)]
    if "ignore" not in feedback:
        feedback_list.append(feedback + " " + str(count))
```

```html
{% for key, value in top_ten_from_article.items() %}
<tr><td>
<input type="radio" name="change_weight_{{ loop.index }}"      value="increase {{ key }}"> <strong>+</strong>
<input type="radio" name="change_weight_{{ loop.index }}" value="ignore {{ key }}" checked><strong>=</strong>
<input type="radio" name="change_weight_{{ loop.index }}" value="decrease {{ key }}"><strong>-</strong>
</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more code that handles the form validation? Also the view function or class that handles the POST request might prove useful. If you can, provide a traceback of the development server.